# Call to undefined function openssl_public_decrypt, mcrypt installed

Tags: php, mcrypt, undefined-function

I try to make a local copy of a wordpress site. I'm using xampp, and everything went just fine up to this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `openssl_public_decrypt()` in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Php info shows that mcrypt is installed, extension_loaded shows also that everything with mcrypt is fine. Any ideas what causing a problem?

Comment: There is a very very little difference between the mcrypt and the openssl extension...

Answer (score 1):

That requires OpenSSL to be installed, as well as PHP 4.0.6

Check out;

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-decrypt.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php